# Can I turn my rigid bodies animation into keyframes?

Tags: keyframes, rigid-body-simulation

I have a very simple rigid body animation, and I want to turn this animation into keyframes. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, go into *Object > Rigid Body > Bake to Keyframes* then in the pop-up panel choose the start and end frames:

[image]

Comment: Thank You so much! Pretty obvious now that I see it LOL